# Trying to make a basic google sheets function with apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Here's the code:

```js
function calculateJuniorCredit() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  for (var i = 2; i <= 45; i++) {

    var classNumber = spreadsheet.getRange(i, 3);

    var juniorCredit = spreadsheet.getRange(4, 12).setValue(0);

    if (classNumber >= 100 && classNumber < 200) {

      juniorCredit.setValue(spreadsheet.getRange(i, 5) + juniorCredit);

    }
  }
}
```

The current issue is that it says that .getRange(i,3) is null, even though there's an integer value in the cell, that being said I'm not very familiar with JS syntax or Apps Script so there's probably other issues. What I'm trying to do is add together all the credits of my 100 level (junior) classes and display the value in cell L4 or (4,12). The class number is found in column C or 3 from rows 2 to 45, and the credit value is in column E or 5.

Comment: Likely `i` or `j` not have proper index values. Why not just use a formula for something like this?

Comment: Simple `=SUMIF()` function should fetch you desired results i believe, could you share input & expected result in a sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Google App Script has multiple .getRange methods. It appears the one you are looking for is under the Sheet Class, not Spreadsheet.

Once you change to the active sheet, then you'll get the proper method with the row and column numbers. You can access the Sheet class by adding on the getActiveSheet method

**Consider updating your spreadsheet variable:**

`var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();`

[Here is the documentation for the Sheet.getRange method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)

Once you open up the documentation, you'll notice that the return type is **Range**.

That's important because your **classNumber** variable is a Range, not a number. So you're checking if the range is equal to 100-199. That conditional will never succeed.

I assume you're meaning to check if the value is equal to any value from 100-199. You might consider using the [**Range.getValue**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) method similar to the Range.setValue method which you're already using.

I'm hoping this points you in the right direction. I don't want to write all the code for ya ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I tried updating the spreadsheet var but when I tried to run it said it couldn't read the property for .getActiveSheet() of null, what does that mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: You can try using the Spreadsheet.getSheetByName like ADW suggested. Depending on how you're implementing it, there might not be an active sheet selected. You can target the sheet you want to use more specifically Here is the documentation for that method:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename

Answer (score 1):

The following line has no meaning and serves no purpose.

```
var app = SpreadsheetApp;
```

The following line gets you the entire file - the spreadsheet. It does not define which tab to use.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

You can fix it the way 8ryan8 suggested, by getting the active tab:

```
var activeSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
```

Or you can get the tab by name:

```
var activeSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Name_of_your_sheet');
```

The following line gets the cell `(i, 3)`. It does not get the value in the cell:

```
var classNumber = spreadsheet.getRange(i, 3);
```

To get the value, use:

```
var classNumber = activeSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
```

The logic of the rest of the code does not make sense. The following line gets the cell L4. And sets the value of L4 to 0.

```
var juniorCredit = spreadsheet.getRange(4, 12).setValue(0);
```

But `juniorCredit` is not a value but a cell.

And `spreadsheet.getRange(i, 5)` is a cell, not the value in the cell.

So in the following won't work:

```
juniorCredit.setValue(spreadsheet.getRange(i, 5) + juniorCredit);
```

I'm not clear on what you are trying to accomplish. You'll need to rethink the logic here.